# Search view domain error

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

There is an odoo system with a timesheet module (self-made) in it. I've made 2 groups of search view filters: *years* and *months*:

```xml
<!--Timesheets-ALL Tab search view-->
    <record id="view_tabel_search3" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search3</field>
            <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Checker">
                <group expand="0" string="Years">
                <filter
                string="Last year"
                name="filter5"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()-relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for last year"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="Current year"
                name="filter4"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for current year"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="Next year"
                name="filter6"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=', (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')),('time_end_t','&lt;=', (context_today()+relativedelt
                help = "Shows timesheets for next year"/>
                </group>
                <group expand="0" string="Months">
                <filter
                string="January"
                name="filter7"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for january"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="February"
                name="filter8"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-03-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for february"/>
                <separator/>
                ...
                <filter
                string="November"
                name="filter17"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-11-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for november"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="December"
                name="filter18"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for december"/>
                </group>
                <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
                <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
            </search>
            </field>
    </record>
```

**time_end_t** and **time_start_t** are dates when our timesheets start and end.
As you can see, *months* itself will show correct timesheets for current year. As well as combination of *Current year* and any *month*. But *last year* and *next year* obviously won't work because of **(context_today())** thing.

The most logic way in my opinion to use **time_end_t**'s year instead of **(context_today())**'s year (which is current only). But I've got an error (in translation) like

```
  Unable to process the search criteria
                 ...
  name 'time_end_t' is not defined
```

when I wrote something like this for example:

```xml
  <field name="time_end_t" />
  <filter
  string="January"
  name="filter7"
  domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' , time_end_t   )]"
  help = "Shows timesheets for january (not actually)"/>
```

But it was defined right above..
Any advice will be highly appreciated!

upd: an example of working code (for Odedra):

```
<page string="Timesheet's data">
    <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <field name="state" widget="statusbar" string="document's status"/>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <group>
        <field name="time_start_t" string="Timesheet's start date" />
        <field name="time_end_t" string="Timesheet's end date" />
    </group></td><td>
    <group>
        <field name="id_division" string="Division" domain="[('enddate','&gt;=',time_start_t),('startdate','&lt;=',time_end_t)  ]"/>
        <field name="id_ank" string="Tableman" />
        <field name="dayall"/>
    </group></td></tr>
    </table>
</page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is OK. When we are using any field on domain than we must register that field. Means we need to define that field at the first line of search view.

Try with this code:

```
<!--Timesheets-ALL Tab search view-->
<record id="view_tabel_search3" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search3</field>
        <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Checker">
            <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
            <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
            <group expand="0" string="Years">
            <filter
            string="Last year"
            name="filter5"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()-relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime(
            help = "Shows timesheets for last year"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter
            string="Current year"
            name="filter4"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
            help = "Shows timesheets for current year"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter
            string="Next year"
            name="filter6"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=', (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')),('time_end_t','&lt;=', (context_today()+relativedelt
            help = "Shows timesheets for next year"/>
            </group>
            <group expand="0" string="Months">
            <filter
            string="January"
            name="filter7"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01'))]"
            help = "Shows timesheets for january"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter
            string="February"
            name="filter8"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-03-01'))]"
            help = "Shows timesheets for february"/>
            <separator/>
            ...
            <filter
            string="November"
            name="filter17"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-11-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01'))]"
            help = "Shows timesheets for november"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter
            string="December"
            name="filter18"
            domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
            help = "Shows timesheets for december"/>
            </group>
        </search>
        </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've hid in comments all the filters except the modified one (january) to be sure it's the one that gives error. Also, I've defined time_start_t, time_end_t and id_ank just like you suggested, unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: @Scraggesh as you write *domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' , time_end_t )]"* we can not write right side *time_end_t* any field name directly. Field value is store at database side. So we need to give right side some value based on field's type. General syntax for domain is: *[('field_name', 'operator', 'value_of_field_which_will_store_in_database')]* for more details you may visit http://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2015/09/domain-in-odoo.html

Comment: Thanks! It may sound weird, but it actually *may* work, that's why I thought we can do things this way. I'll add a working example to my question up here.

Comment: Yes you are right it will work fine on form view. But, In *Search/Filter view* it will not work. You must have to define some value in right side, it will not consider field name. If you give field name than it will raise error like *name 'field_name' is not defined*