# Proper years/months filter realization

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In addition to [Search view domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012722/search-view-domain-error) (I've accepted the answer since my theory of how to make proper years/months filter in a selfmade timesheet module appeared to be wrong. That was an answer about *why I'm getting an error*. Answer: because my method was wrong. Here I'm asking about *how to make it properly*).

So, a quick overview. Selfmade timesheet module. 2 groups of search view filters: *years* and *months*. Is there any way to make *months* group depend on *years* group, like if I chose some year, *months* group will now be related to that particular year? 
Some code examples below:

```xml
<!--Timesheets-ALL Tab search view-->
    <record id="view_tabel_search3" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">tabel.tabel.search3</field>
            <field name="model">tabel.tabel</field>
            <field name="type">search</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Checker">
                <field name="time_start_t" select="True"/>
                <field name="id_ank" select="True"/>
                <group expand="0" string="Years">
                <filter
                string="Last year"
                name="filter5"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()-relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for last year"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="Current year"
                name="filter4"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for current year"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="Next year"
                name="filter6"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=', (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y-01-01')),('time_end_t','&lt;=', (context_today()+relativedelt
                help = "Shows timesheets for next year"/>
                </group>
                <group expand="0" string="Months">
                <filter
                string="January"
                name="filter7"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-01-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for january"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="February"
                name="filter8"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-02-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-03-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for february"/>
                <separator/>
                ...
                <filter
                string="November"
                name="filter17"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-11-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01'))]"
                help = "Shows timesheets for november"/>
                <separator/>
                <filter
                string="December"
                name="filter18"
                domain="[('time_end_t', '&gt;=' ,(context_today()).strftime('%Y-12-01')), ('time_end_t', '&lt;' , (context_today()+relativedelta(years=1)).strftime(
                help = "Shows timesheets for december"/>
                </group>
            </search>
            </field>
    </record>
```

**time_end_t** and **time_start_t** are dates when our timesheets start and end.
As you can see, *months* itself will show correct timesheets for current year. As well as combination of *Current year* and any *month*. But *last year* and *next year* obviously won't work because of **(context_today())** thing.

The most logic way in my opinion was to use **time_end_t**'s year instead of **(context_today())**'s year (which is current only). But as I was told in my prev. answer, it's a wrong idea. So.. As always, any advice will be highly appreciated!

2015-10-20upd: After a long break I'm returning to this problem, still no idea though, also I was wondering, is it possible to change filter rule from "and" to "or"? For example, if I've checked january and november, I would like to see timesheets for both that months, not the timesheets that start in january and end in november. Without that  thing only the last month filter works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search view domain error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012722/search-view-domain-error)

Comment: Not a duplicate, just another question on the same direction. I've asked why I have an error, while doing X and I was told that I can't do it that way. Here I'm asking how am I supposed to do X.
I think I had to open new question, since I've got an answer for previous one.